# How to sync onedrive for business?

Tags: sync, cloud, dropbox, microsoft-office

At my school we are starting to implement Office 365 for our students. We are working on basis of a bring-your-own-device strategy and will meet all kinds of devices and OS's. Office 365 comes with a built-in cloud feature, which can be synced to a newer Windows machine. Is there a possibility to sync to Ubuntu or Lubuntu machine, as it is possible with fx Dropbox?
Thanks for helping.
Armin

Answer (score 1):

One Drive business (former Skydrive Business) also used as Sync tool for SharePoint has no native client for Linux. It is based on the Groove tool MS had back in the days.

For now you can only use the web browser to upload/download files.

Your best bet is that for OneDrive a Linux client/tool/daemon (like http://xybu.me/projects/onedrive-d/) will be built and that OneDrive Business support to use the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can synchronize Ubuntu with oneDrive but not with the busines version. So use the free version and it works well. There is solution for ubuntu 14-04. I use it on 15 and it works fine.
[How to sync OneDrive on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676210/how-to-sync-onedrive-on-ubuntu-14-04)
All what I have to do is some minor adjustment - not reported on other ubuntu machines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution: not a sync but a full access is possible with `spfilezilla`.

Download `spfilezilla`

Install `mono-complete` package

```
sudo apt install mono-complete
```

Run spfilezilla with mono

```
mono spfilezilla.exe
```

Configure it

Download link: https://spfilezilla.codeplex.com/downloads/get/1488499
There you get the source code and binary (in bin/Debug folder).
Be adviced that currently the download feature is in progress due to a missing token.
The problem is in spcomhelper.cs file at line

```
var fi = File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, fileServerRelUrl);
```

which is not able to generate the temporary token needed to download the single file.

Enjoy

Comment: Added, check above

Answer (score 0):

A working SPfilezilla has been uploaded here: https://github.com/suoko/spfilezilla

Answer (score -1):

The Microsoft Office on-line has integration with Dropbox, as you can see in this link: [Microsoft Office for Dropbox — Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/7037#). And there's a Dropbox client available at Ubuntu Software Centre, and also in the official website: https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx.
So, should work fine.