# Office365 SharePoint sync

Tags: sync, microsoft, office365

I am trying to make a sync with SharePoint from my company.
I was trying the method available here : [How to Sync OneDrive Business /Office 365 on Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804301/how-to-sync-onedrive-business-office-365-on-linux).
But the sync is not running.

```
gsync sync "OneDrive_Sync"
FirstOpt=sync Profile=/home/blazej4wise/.goodsync
FirstAfterLogOpts=sync Profile=/home/blazej4wise/.goodsync
Loaded 1 jobs from /home/blazej4wise/.goodsync/jobs-groups-options.tix.
JobCmd=sync JobName=

=== Job === OneDrive_Sync: 'office365://4wisegroup.sharepoint.com/sites/WsparcieTechniczne/Shared%20Documents' <-> 'file:///your_home_folder/one_drive_folder'
111939 L: No file system for office365://4wisegroup.sharepoint.com/sites/WsparcieTechniczne/Shared%20Documents
File system at office365://4wisegroup.sharepoint.com/sites/WsparcieTechniczne/Shared%20Documents has been replaced by New OneDrive V2 API.
Click Browse button to Re-Browse to your OneDrive sync folder, as New OneDrive requires browser-based authentication (OAuth2)
```

How do I resolve this error?