# What is the best way to synch One Drive business folder to Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, sync, microsoft

I am looking for a way to sync my One Drive (business) onto my computer with the OS Ubuntu 18.04. I have seen a few unofficial packages like onedrive-D that do not support the business version and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804301/how-to-sync-onedrive-business-office-365-on-linux/804330) from 3 years ago.

I was wondering if there is a new 3rd party way to sync OneDrive with ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I have not yet encountered a better way than the one I described in my answer to the linked question, but I also didn't investigate much further since then.

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for a way to sync my One Drive (business) onto my computer with the OS Ubuntu 18.04

I am the developer of the Linux OneDrive Client: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

Fully supports:

- OneDrive Business
- OneDrive Business Shared Folders
- SharePoint Drives