# How to Sync OneDrive Business (Office 365) on Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: sync

I tried the solution proposed by Sayed Metwaly ([How to Sync OneDrive Business /Office 365 on Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804301/how-to-sync-onedrive-business-office-365-on-linux)) but I got the following error message:

```
=== Job === OneDrive_Sync: 'office365://xxxxxxxxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxxxxx_oasis_xxxxxxxxx_be/Documents' <-> 'file:///home/xxxxxx/Onedrive'
142724 L: No file system for office365://xxxxxxxxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxxxxx_oasis_xxxxxxxxx_be/Documents
File system at office365://xxxxxxxxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxxxxx_oasis_xxxxxxxxx_be/Documents has been replaced by New OneDrive V2 API.
Click Browse button to Re-Browse to your OneDrive sync folder, as New OneDrive requires browser-based authentication (OAuth2)
```

Any idea on what I did wrong? Thanks

Comment: Have you actually read the error message you pasted here?

Comment: Oh yes, I did! I do not see any "Browse" button anywhere ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sync onedrive for business?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537476/how-to-sync-onedrive-for-business)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did to get it working very quickly:

1. Used a Windows machine to set up a sync using the Windows version of Goodsync.  This includes setting up the (browser-based) authorization with Office 365.
2. Used the "Export" option in the Windows version of Goodsync to create a `jobs.tix` file.
3. Created a `~/.goodsync` folder on the Linux machine.
4. Placed the `jobs.tix` file in that folder.
5. This is a NEW STEP I had to discover on my own: RENAMED the `jobs.tix` file to `jobs-groups-options.tix` — this allowed the entire configuration to be used.
6. Applied the following changes, as shown by the `diff` output from the original Windows `jobs.tix` file:

   ```
   $ diff ~/Downloads/jobs.tix ~/.goodsync/jobs-groups-options.tix
   51c51
   <     Url = "file://"
   –––
   >     Url = "file:///home/tomh/onedrive"
   54c54
   <   Url = "file:///~tomh-a/od"
   –––
   >   Url = "file:///home/tomh/onedrive"
   68c68
   <  } Bookmarks = { }   TimeStamp = 013061702176
   –––
   >  } Bookmarks = { }   TimeStamp = 013061705503
   84c84
   <     Url = "file:///~tomh-a/od"
   –––
   >     Url = "file:///home/tomh/onedrive"
   87c87
   <   AcctUrl = "file:///~tomh-a/od"
   –––
   >   AcctUrl = "file:///home/tomh/onedrive"
   ```

   Where `tomh-a` is my Windows username, `od` was my local Windows OneDrive folder, `tomh` is my Linux username, and `onedrive` is my local Linux OneDrive folder. You can safely ignore the `TimeStamp` lines, I just left them in for completeness. Note that this `diff` output was **not sanitized or changed** in any way except to replace certain characters with the corresponding HTML entities. So yes, you all now know my Windows and Linux user names and OneDrive sync folders. Can't see how that compromises my security, and it improves the chances that it is typo-free.
7. One obscure thing I changed that make it work: You'll find these two lines in the file:

   ```
   Side2 = <SideOptions>
   Conn = <Connect>
   ```

   I changed the second line as follows:

   ```
   Side2 = <SideOptions>
   Dir = <Connect>
   ```

   and it immediately started working.
    *Disclaimer: After I ran the sync (next step) Goodsync changed the line back to `Conn = <Connect>`. So I could be wrong. Maybe I could have left it as-was (and is again). But that's the last change I made before it started working. It's entirely possible that I changed something else at the same time that made it work.  But at least making that change didn't* break *it for me :)*
8. Run the sync with

   ```
   gsync sync "Onedrive"
   ```

   substituting "Onedrive" with whatever appears in the lines that look like:

   ```
   Jobs = { <Job>
   Name = "Onedrive"
   ```

It is my belief that the API v2.0 requirement of using OAuth has made it impossible to simply take someone else's `jobs-groups-options.tix` file and make it work for yourself simply using Linux. That is, until they decide to make a GUI version for Linux — or at least add the OAuth code that launches your browser to establish the authorization.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem today. What worked for me in the end, was to download and use GoodSync GUI on a Windows machine and port the final configuration over to my Linux machine.

On Windows, I configured my Business OneDrive following [these instructions](http://www.goodsync.com/how-to-sync-onedrive-office365). Next, I used the GUI's "export selected jobs" function (right click the job name) to export a `jobs.tix` file. This is the configuration file you need.

On Ubuntu, paste the `jobs.tix` file into `~/.goodsync/` and edit it in a text editor to update the client-side url to the appropriate folder in your local file system. Finally, just run `gsync sync [jobname]` to synchronize all files. This worked for me both upstream and downstream.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to work also for me. I guess the synchonization is not automatic and that we have to run manually `gsync sync xxxx` to synchronize files.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a sanitized version of your `jobs.tix` file?  It might be possible for other people to edit it to suit their needs, instead of going via Windows.

Comment: @NateEldredge: The `jobs.tix` file is structured like what @Joop posted in his answer, but most of the fields are encrypted. I can't tell which encryption is used, and for security reasons I also can't post my file here. In any case, the encryption makes it hard for other users to edit the file manually, and I would still recommend them to go via Windows as I have outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Job>
 2 Name = "name"
 3 Side1 = <SideOptions>
 4 Dir = <Connect>
 5     Url = "file:///home/username/path/bla"
 6 </Connect>
 7 </SideOptions>
 8 Side2 = <SideOptions>
 9 Dir = <Connect>
10     Url = "msdrive://<compname>-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/me"
11     UserID = "myid+somegarbleinhex"
12     AccessToken = "blaaaah"
13     RefreshToken = "blaaahA"
14 </Connect>
15   UseTmpDestFile = No
16 </SideOptions>
17 Direction = 0
   ExcludeHidden = Yes
   ExcludeSystem = Yes
   DetectMovesAndRenames = Yes
   LinksOption = 1
   </Job>
```

Comment: Can you please give more context to this answer and explain it? Right now, all this answer does is give the OP something to copy and paste without understanding it. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/850864/edit) your answer to include an explanation and more context/steps.