# OneDrive_Sync: No file system for office365

Tags: 17.10, office365

I am trying to sync Office365 with my Ubuntu 17.10 machine.
I installed Goodsync and followed the instructions from this post:
[How to Sync OneDrive Business /Office 365 on Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804301/how-to-sync-onedrive-business-office-365-on-linux?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Unfortunately, I have the exact same error message as posted here:
[How to Sync OneDrive Business (Office 365) on Linux (Ubuntu)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830610/how-to-sync-onedrive-business-office-365-on-linux-ubuntu)

Which is:

```
=== Job === OneDrive_Sync: 'office365://xxxxxxxxx-my.sharepoint.com//Documents' <-> 'file:///Home/OneDrive 
142724 L: No file system for office365://xxxxxxxxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxxxx_myaddress_XXXX 
File system at office365://xxxxxxxxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxxxx_myaddress_XXXX has been replaced by New OneDrive V2 API. 
Click Browse button to Re-Browse to your OneDrive sync folder, as New OneDrive requires browser-based authentication (OAuth2)
```

I followed the instruction given in the aforementioned post, but it did not solved the issue.

It seems to be an url problem but I cannot found the correct one.

Any idea welcome.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use "Documents" in cojunction with Online Accounts? If you set up 'Online Accounts' with your MSFT account you should be able to sync your documents. I don't know if Office 360 offers some special api's via GoodSync. Always use the built-in tools if at all possible.

Comment: MSFT account and 365 pro account are very different. I have no problem to sync my regular MSFT account but not my 365 pro account.
Of course I can always access it online but that is not the point.

Comment: O OK @Pierre Blanche thanks for clearing that up for me. Sorry, I'm unable to help as I don't use that service.